# Revit API is Reading the Wrong Type Parameters Values

Tags: c#, api, autodesk, revit

I've developed a family browser, where I can search and find families and can read their additional information. However, the value I'm reading for type parameter is different from one shows in the Revit 2017. Below is the screenshot of property window of my application and Revit 2017. Here the **value displays for Dimension's Depth is different from one I can see in the Revit**.

[image: Type parameter values are not matching]

Here is the **code behind**:

```
 static string FamilyParamValueString(FamilyType t, FamilyParameter fp, Document doc)
        {


            string value = t.AsValueString(fp);


            switch (fp.StorageType)
            {
                case StorageType.Double:
                    value = Util.RealString(
                      (double)t.AsDouble(fp))
                      + " (double)";

                    break;

                case StorageType.ElementId:
                    ElementId id = t.AsElementId(fp);
                    Element e = doc.GetElement(id);
                    value = id.IntegerValue.ToString() + " ("
                      + Util.ElementDescription(e) + ")";
                    break;

                case StorageType.Integer:
                    value = t.AsInteger(fp).ToString()
                      + " (int)";
                    break;

                case StorageType.String:
                    value = "'" + t.AsString(fp)
                      + "' (string)";
                    break;
            }

            return value;
        }
```

here's how I'm calling the **FamilyParamValueString** method.

```
 foreach (FamilyType familytype in mgr.Types)
            {

                string name = familytype.Name;
                MultiValueDictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>> Parameters = new MultiValueDictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>>();

                foreach (string key in keys)
                {
                    FamilyParameter fp = fps[key];
                    var definition = fp.Definition;
                    string ParameterGroupid = LabelUtils.GetLabelFor(definition.ParameterGroup);

                    if (familytype.HasValue(fp))
                    {
                        // Reading type's parameter value
                        string value = FamilyParamValueString(familytype, fp, doc);

                        //store parameter information along with its group
                        Parameters.Add(ParameterGroupid, new Tuple<string, string>(key, value));

                    }
                }



            }
```

Please guide me, how I can able to read exactly the same values as it displays in the Revit type's properties. Thank you for support!

Comment: Also discussed in the Revit API discussion forum: https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/converting-all-parameter-values-from-imperial-units-to-metric/td-p/7699457 and https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/reading-wrong-type-parameters-values/td-p/7693089/jump-to/first-unread-message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's related to units. The value returned by the parameter is in Revit's internal units of feet (ft), while the values you see on the screen are in mm, cm, m or whatever else you have set for that model. Just convert from internal to display and you will be fine.

Here's a utility method for doing the conversion: http://www.revitapidocs.com/2018/9cc2c0ea-f59f-9d76-ce19-ae7eede03bbd.htm

Cheers!